# вставка символа в строку

Tags: c++, строки

Задача простая - есть строка, например std::string("sfsfsgsdshhdfjj"), необходимо вставить через каждый второй символ символ "-".Не пойму как такое реализовать, пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: Не правьте, пожалуйста, вопросы, изменяя метки, меняя точки на запятые и добавляя кавычки/ненужные метки, зарабатывая по +2 репутации. Вносите бОльшие изменения в вопрос, чтобы он был полезней, либо не меняйте его. Это не приносит пользы вопросам и сообществу в целом. Спасибо.

Comment: @Denis - пожалуйста! Исправлять орфографические ошибки и правила расстановки знаков препинания не нужно? Нет? Делать вопросы более понятными для всех не нужно???  Я все исправляю по правилам форума. Я не просто зарабатываю 2 балла репутации - но и делаю полезное дело! И да -  это приносит пользу сообществу!

Comment: Например, вот [эта правка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/107282) не несёт пользы вопросу - кавычки тут не нужны, как и точка после ссылки, есть даже причина для отклонения таких правок - `"Правка никак не делает сообщения более простым к прочтению, не упрощает его поиск, точность или доступность. Изменения абсолютно излишни или явно ухудшают читаемость."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ, пожалуй, - создать новую строку и посимвольно туда запихивать все это хозяйство.

Что-то вроде

```
string s("sfsfsgsdshhdfjj");
string d;
for(auto c: s) { d += c; d += '-'; }
```

**Update**
Как оказалось, не совсем верно понял, дефис надо через два на третий...
Примерно так:

```
string d;
for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
{
    d += s[i++];
    if (i < s.length())
    {
        d += s[i];
        d += '-';
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы добавил: `d.reserve(s.length()*2-1)`

Comment: Да, согласен, несколько быстрее. Тут - http://ideone.com/Jmlwde - сравнение с резервированием, без и с методом вставкой.

Comment: А вообще, самый быстрый вот такой: http://ideone.com/B4C7xG объясняю почему: `operator[]` не выполняет никаких проверок вообще, а `operator+=` - выполняет. Как минимум - вдруг ёмкость исчерпалась, а значит нужно как бы и памяти добавить. Правило наименьшего оверхеда вкупе с наименьшим удивлением. Ваш вариант ещё и ошибку содержит: всегда добавляется `-` во конце, хотя не должен вообще. Пруф: http://ideone.com/VbE5RW

Answer (score 1):

Решение @Harry быстрое, а если жалко памяти на два буффера сразу, то можно либо как у вас или так (дополнительной памяти O(1)):

```
// Резервируем память, что бы исключить реаллокации при вставке
s.reserve(s.length()*3/2);
for (size_t i = 2; i < s.length(); i+=2)
    s.insert(i++, 1, '-'); // инкремент тут нужен, что бы уйти с только что вставленного '-'
```

Минус: оно медленное за счёт того, что при каждой вставке нужно делать `memmove`/`memcpy` для оставшихся символов.

Проверка: http://ideone.com/SAQCkz

**UPD**: поправлено под условие (каждый второй символ)

**UPD2**: самый (пока?) шустрый вариант (дополнительной памяти O(n)):

```
string str;
str.resize(s.length() * 3/2);
size_t size = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    str[size++] = s[i++];
    if (i < s.length()) {
        str[size++] = s[i];
        if (i != s.length() - 1)
            str[size++] = '-';
    }
}
// ;-)
str.resize(size);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/B4C7xG

Сравнение: http://ideone.com/VbE5RW

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я придумал:

```
std::string tempStr;

for (size_t i(0), j(0); i < tempStr.size(); i++, j++)
    {
        if (j > 1) {

            tempStr.insert(i, "-");
            j = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А, так вам каждый третий надо вставлять? я вас не так понял. Но принцип не меняется :) У вас же основное - вставка посредине - операция дорогостоящая...

Comment: Я свое решение подправил, смотрите здесь - http://ideone.com/Jmlwde - и там же ваше, с проверкой времени. Причем учтите, что у вас что-то типа O(N^2) получается, так что если длину строки в 10 раз увеличить, ideone ругается - превышен лимит времени...

Comment: @Harry - да все нормально, и так работает, тебе спасибо за вариант